# add href link to <a> Tag in css

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have  dynamic table .in which data populates from DB asHyperlink Records

this is script:

```
function getErrorStatusList() {
});
$.ajax({
   // parameters
    success: function (response) {
//Data gets in response
var output = "<table class='table'><tr><th>MZillaID</th></tr>";

        for (var x = 0; x < obj.length; x++) {

            output += "<tr><td class='myclass' style='text-decoration:underline;'>" + obj[x].EMID + "</td></tr>";
        }

        output += "</table>";
        $("#result").append(output);

    },

});
```

this is working Fine .this records generated to hyperlink in Output HTML

as

```
<a href="http://mzillaint.nokia.com/show_bug.cgi?id=87774">87774</a>
```

..I want to put this on Css.I mean add "a" tag in css and put href in it

like

```
a
{
    href://link which generated 

}
```

I Tried But this is not implementing ..How Can I do it ??Any suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: What is the purpose of what you're trying to do? Do you want to style links differently based on the href attribute, or something else?

Comment: My problem is that my Hyperlink records dont look as hyperlink on page load ...I have to add "td class='myclass' style='text-decoration:underline;'" .... to Show as hyprlnklink ..I want to make it using css

Comment: Is there a style somewhere it your CSS files that is overwriting the default?

Answer (score 0):

It is absolutely not possible. You can not modify DOM using CSS as CSS is display only.

You should rather use javascript or jquery to do that after appending the DOM.

```
 $("#result").append(output);
 $("#result a").attr('href',generated_link_here);
```

Comment: this code started to add color  ...........$('#result a:link').css({
               color: 'blue',
               text-decoration:'underline'

            });.......But my underline functionality is not working ..

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to implement that 
$('a').attr('href','http://mzillaint.nokia.com/show_bug.cgi?id=87774');